# Working at django templates without django forms

Tags: django, django-templates, pymongo

I need simple example , Creating django templates without creating django forms which I can enter some information at templates and I need to save in mongo db at views part. Currently I am using pymongo.

Please post some examples

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow: Your question is _Too Broad_. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create file simple.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="myform" method="post" action="/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="var" value="15" />
            <a href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();return false;">Let's go!</a>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>


And Write the view

def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            var = request.POST['var']
            # TODO use var
        except :
            print 'Where is my var?'
    return render_to_response('simple.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))



Is this one you are looking for?
```